# How can I add textbox in last column of listview in UWP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I wanted to add `textbox` below whenever last columns of `listview` in `UWP`.

Thins is my **MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView x:Name="MyList">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding todo}" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding checkList}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

if I put `TextBox` inside `StackPanel`. The `textbox` shows inside the column. 
But I was wondering how can I add `textbox` below whenever last column is.

Thank you so much:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you first want to show all items in your `ListView` and then a single `TextBox` below the last item?

Simply take the `TextBox` outside the `ListView`.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel>
        <ListView x:Name="MyList">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding todo}" ></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding checkList}"></TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

I have used a `StackPanel` to place them below each other, you can however also use `RowDefinition`s. Pick whichever layout fits your needs.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ListView x:Name="MyList" Grid.Row="0">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding todo}" ></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding checkList}"></TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding date}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Grid.Row="1" />
</Grid>
```

Notice that I have also removed the `Grid` in your `DataTemplate` as it was not necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much :) and i add relativePanel :)